# How to use python to delete a column and rows in excel, that contains certain values

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

Just trying to get python to open a file,  read a file,  do value set in which if the data that has a 1.00 and has another value thats over 0.93 in that row/column then it  gets deleted, if not then go over row/column to the next row/column, both files are closed, then rename new file into original file

Answer (score 1):

There is a package named xlrd that you can use to read data from excel file and modify/delete to suit your need.